# Looping Child arrayList in Parent ArrayList

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

### Problem

- I need to create an invoice using pure javascript
- Input(Checkbox) have ID's and Values

  > `<input type="checkbox" id="2Tier" value="950"/>`
- When user clicks $("input[type=checkbox]"), $(this) gets the id and value and sets them to $selectedWeddingCake and $price and then passes them as an array

> `$selectedWeddingCake = [$weddingCake, $price, $total];`

- then push this list into the invoice list

  > `$ListItem.push($selectedWeddingCake);`

now my problem is that i need to create an invoice that displays all the selected cakes.

my for for loop hangs when i call it to display just one item

---

### My for Loop

```
for (i = 0; i <= $ListItem.length; i += 1) {

    for (j = 0; i <= $selectedWeddingCake.length; j += 1) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<br>Item: " + $selectedWeddingCake[i] + "<br>Price: " + $selectedWeddingCake[i] + "<br>Total: " + $selectedWeddingCake[i];
    }
}
```

> `ListItem[0]-->selectedWeddingCake[$weddingCake, $price, $total];`

---

### Desired loop output

> `The selected Cake is $weddingCake`
>   `The price is $price`
>   `The Total is $total`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't change a letter in the second index:

```
for (i = 0; i <= $ListItem.length; i += 1) {

    for (j = 0; j <= $selectedWeddingCake.length; j += 1) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<br>Item: " + $selectedWeddingCake[i] + "<br>Price: " + $selectedWeddingCake[i] + "<br>Total: " + $selectedWeddingCake[i];
    }
}
```

The condition is `j <= $selectedWeddingCake.length;`, not `i <= $selectedWeddingCake.length;`

Cheers

Comment: So roberto, Im a bit confused with my code, Its giving me all the index[1]. I want the index of selectedWeddingCake[0][1][2]. how can i achieve this?

Comment: Is j also in the append code :) `$selectedWeddingCake[j]` instead of `$selectedWeddingCake[i]`